# How to prevent spamming of AWS cloud front?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am learning AWS , and came across hosting static websites using Amazon S3 and distributing to edge locations using Cloud Front and Route53.

I know that for Cloud front we pay for what we use. So my monthly bill will reflect the number of requests I get once the free tier is over.

My question is what if a hacker or someone sends a lots of requests like spamming, then will I be charged higher?
How to prevent this and does AWS has any security measures like limiting the number of requests to serve per minute or something for this ?

Pardon me if my question is very basic. I am just learning . Thanks

Comment: This is an interesting question, yes AWS charge for the request and you're in the same situation as S3 where 403 counts as number of requests and you get charged, the most you can do on CloudFront is to use WAF and atleast deny those incoming request because you don't want to get charge for Data transfer out if the spammer is requesting for a legitimate file. see : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=59240 this isn't specific to AWS, this is for any public website but AWS provides a way to protect them using WAF or Shield (additional cost).

Comment: Thanks @James , will take a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is what if a hacker or someone sends a lots of requests like spamming, then will I be charged higher?

Yes. You are charged a per-request price, as well as data transfer charges. The per-request charges are relatively low, but if they find a large file to download they can quickly run up the bandwidth charge.

> does AWS has any security measures like limiting the number of requests to serve per minute or something for this ?

Yes, you want [WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/how-aws-waf-works.html), the Web Application Firewall. With it you can configure a rate-limited rule that will block an IP address after N requests within a five-minute period.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will check this out.

Answer (score -1):

As I know you pay for Caches Invalidations on AWS but not for a number of requests done to your CloudFront distributions.

Comment: You should review the pricing page: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/, and scroll down to "Request Pricing for All HTTP Methods". There's also a charge for data transfer.

Comment: Thanks @Anton for the answer, but I think we do pay for the number of requests 